# Cardinality of a special system of edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

There is given a complete graph $B=K_{n}$.

I make a special set of marked edges. Lets call it $A$. Its construction is following:

Let $k=0$ and $A$ is empty and it has the same vertices as $B$.

First step. I add to $A$ any edge from $B$.

Next steps. If there exists new edge $e$ which is adjacent to $k$ edges from $A$, then i add $e$ to $A$. Otherwise i add a one to $k$.

Finally. Algorithm stops when every $l$-clique from $B$ has at least one edge from $A$.

> How many edges $A$ contain?

I know the topic is connected with finding independent set of edges, but i can't find a application of it here.

Maybe some of you see the solution?

Regards.

Comment: Do you have any restriction on $\ell$? is it fixed? otherwise if you need any clique, this include all 2-cliques, hence all edges

Comment: $l$ is fixed natural number.